# Create a WORD CLOUD in Google Data Studio

Tags: data-visualization, looker-studio, word-cloud

I'm trying to create a word cloud in Google Data Studio. In order to do that as quickly as I can I wanted to use the community visualization. (https://github.com/pcperini/GDS-Word-Cloud , https://marketlytics.com/blog/custom-visualizations-data-studio ).

Unfortunately anytime I try to insert the manifest path (gs://gds-word-cloud-prod) in the community visualization archive, it doesn't find anything.

Do you have any suggestions? Am I doing something wrong? Are these visualization too old?

Comment: Hey! I've found an [issue opened](https://github.com/pcperini/GDS-Word-Cloud/issues/1) that could be related with your case.
If this is the issue you are facing, I would recommend you to follow the the thread in Github in order to follow up any updates.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, the default Vega Chart (in the [Community Visualization](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9206527) toolbar) offers a Word Cloud.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/9223eb6a-9c74-45bd-bdcc-bd3282362743) to demonstrate as well as a GIF showing the process:

[image: 3]]

Answer (score 0):

The community visualization you listed `gs://gds-word-cloud-prod`, is no longer supported, so it will not load. You should try using a different visualization ID.